# Complete Cygwin packages download

Tags: cygwin

I am fond of Unix/Linux tools,So I install the Cygwin.My problem is each time I need a tool I has to download it separately,besides the download rate is pretty low.

Is there anyone knows a good resource of a complete packages of all the tools ?

Having the complete packages we can just download it once and install it using Cygwin's 'install from local directory' option.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.everything) on the Cygwin site. If the link doesn't work for you, look for "How do I just get everything" in the FAQ. Note, however that it's rather rare to actually install all of Cygwin. I've been using Cygwin for many years, and I'm sure I have far less than half of it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the tools you want in setup, and it will retain your settings.

[image: Typical package selection]

Initially you will add tools, but as your workflow becomes complete, you will add tools much less frequently. Downloading everything always is a less effective approach.